# What is an idiom for "increase" / "generate more" / "intensify in ridiculous amounts"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

I'm trying to search for idioms to express "increase" or "generate more" or "boost" or "magnify" in terms of business profits. Basically, I'm looking for another way to express "...to generate more revenue for your business.

Comment: to pump out profits, to spew out profits

Comment: *Maximise* profits.